# Is "we" an imperative?

Tags: personal-pronouns, imperatives

Is the english use of "we" an example of an imperative in "We forced our backs...we cursed through sludge" ?

I think it sort of is, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Why do you think those phrases are imperative?

Comment: Oh; that wasn't quite what I meant, but so am I. I wonder if there is some confusion with an implied imperative like "We don't have enough time to walk, so **we go by car,** don't we?" In the wrong hands that can be very sarcastic.

Comment: No, it's not an imperative at all. "Let's" is more imperative-like. Lots of things may be said with an imperative implication, e.g. if your mom says "It sure looks like rain out" might be taken to imply that you should get out your umbrella, but the dictionary meaning is not at all imperative.

Comment: One possible example I can think of is "we *will* be respected."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imperative is formed by suppressing the pronouns like in :

> Have fun.
>
> Enjoy your meal.
>
> Stop talking and open your books.
>
> Don’t be late.

you can see them [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/imperative-clauses-be-quiet).

`We` is just a group of people including you not an imperative form.

Answer (score 2):

A pronoun cannot be imperative.
In your case, "we" is just an ordinary pronoun in the plural.

Perhaps you think about
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we
?